# How to read in txt file with multiple Lines of Strings

Tags: java, linked-list, bufferedreader

I'm trying to make an array of strings using a list of names coming from a txt file. 
So for example: If I have string[] names = {all the names from the txtfile(one name perline)} 
I want to pass "names" into a method that takes in a array like "names"(the one I made above). The method will then run the names through another for loop and create a linked list. I'm really confusing myself on this and tried number of things but nothing seems to work. Right now It'll print out the first name correctly but every name after that just says null. So I have about 70 nulls being printed out.

```
         public static void main(String[] args) {


        //String[] names = {"Billy Joe", "Alan Bowe", "Sally Mae", "Joe Blow", "Tasha Blue", "Malcom Floyd"}; // Trying to print theses names..Possibly in alphabetical order

        BigNode x = new BigNode(); 

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter File Name: ");
        String Finame = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You Entered " + Finame);

        try {File file = new File(Finame);
        BufferedReader readers = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
       // String nameLine = ;
        String[] name;
        name = new String[73];
        String[] nameTO;
        String nameLine;
      //  while ((nameLine = readers.readLine()) != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){


        name[i] = readers.readLine();


        x.populateNodes(name);

        } //}
        } catch(IOException e) {

        }
```

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, please add the 'homework' tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is x.populateNodes(name) inside the loop? Wouldn't you be populating it after filling your array?

Since I've no idea what BigNode is, I assume it should be one of the following
`x.populateNodes(name[i])` inside the loop or `x.populateNodes(name)` outside the loop.

Comment: lol no lie I tried that before and it crashed on me giving me a nullpointer error and I tried it again and now it works. I don't understand but thank you

Comment: This turned out to be a wasted of question for me for such a little mistake. Sorry about that

Comment: Because now I need to figure out how to print out all the people who's name starts with a certain letter that the user would ask for.

Comment: yea I had to wait a couple minutes before it let me.